# CQRS/DDD How would add an object to an aggregate using a command?

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, aggregateroot

I'm very new to CQRS/DDD, so there may be big holes in my understanding.

But let's suppose I have an aggregate object, `Widget`. `Widget` is composed with `Note` objects and `Note` objects can have a `File` object attached to them.

In CQRS I might have a command called `AddNoteToWidget`. I know from my reading that both command and event objects should be simple DTO's (I know they can also come in other forms, but the key thing being that they contain no behaviour).

I also understand that entities should never contain references to repositories since they should be persistence unaware.

Would my `AddNoteToWidget` contain a reference to the `File` object and just be serialized along with the command? If this is the case then my `File` object should be a value object. However, I have modelled it as an entity with it's own repository because I wanted to have central consistent file storage across the whole system.

Comment: I would not add a serialized file to your command. Use Filename/path instead for new files or use the internal Id of the File (Entity) for existing one.

Comment: Note could have the file reference, but addNoteToWidget should not.

Comment: I've removed the las paragraph -- SO doesn't like link only answers, and your question would be closed and removed if it were to stand.

Comment: @Jehof Ok so if I use the ID of the `File` entity, would I not then need a reference to the `FileRepository` in `Widget`. Or would you simply get the file ID and query the `FileRepository` in the client code?

Comment: @EngineerDollery ok, so `AddNoteToWidget` might have a string for the note and then the ID of the `File` entity?

Comment: Not really, files have nothing to do with widgets. The note may have a reference to a file (an ID), that may be present when you add the note to the widget (or may not be present, depending on your design), but the widget knows and cares nothing about files.

Comment: @EngineerDollery ok yeah that's what I thought. But it would be nice if the `Note` when reconstructed from whatever persistence had an actual reference to the `File` entity, rather than an ID that would require the client code to query the `FileRepository`. However I can't see how this is possible if I'm simply replaying command objects that must be simple DTOs

Comment: By giving it a repo I think you've modeled file as an aggregate root, which means it is accessed independently, as you mention. This is a highly desirable quality that you should welcome, as it allows the reuse of the file concept across many different classes of entity, and it allows implementations to use microservice architectures and to be deployed and scaled independently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From reading your question as well as the comments on it, it is clear that **you currently treat `File` as both a sub-entity and an aggregate root**. This is a problem, you should decide for one of the two:

1. Model `File` as an aggregate. Now only the ID of a `File` must be used outside of that aggregate, never the `File` itself. Also, `File` objects are retrieved through their own repository.
2. Model `File` as entity within the `Widget` aggregate. This means that you have the file readily available whenever you have a `Widget`. `File` objects don't have their own repository, they are loaded together with a `Widget` through the `WidgetRepository`.

Which of the two is better in your case I cannot tell from your question. As a guideline, aggregate boundaries are *consistency boundaries*, and aggregates are always persisted atomically. An app service should only modify a single aggregate.

I think the main problem that you currently have can be summarized as follows:

> *Repositories* handle only whole *Aggregates*, never single *Entities* that are part of an *Aggregate*.

Of course, there may be simple aggregates that consist only of one entity, in that case, the entity and the aggregate are the same.